# How do I do traceroute/tracepath without any admin privileges?

Tags: networking, security, linux-networking, icmp, traceroute

Basically, I need to "trace a packet from my computer to the host" to diagnose a network issue and I do not need any fancy additional functionality.

---

Redirect me to the right place if this is not the place for this question, but I need to do something like traceroute/tracepath/tracert, but I have no admin privileges and I do not have these utilities installed. I think that the admin might have deliberately removed or disabled tracert. All I have is Java 8, Python 3, cygwin, and Windows 7. I can set local environment variables (ex. PATH, JAVA_HOME, etc) and I can put things in my home directory, but I cannot do full installations. Do you have or know of a way to do traceroute/tracepath/tracert given these limitations?

---

I am considering [these repos](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Traceroute%20stars%3A%3E40&type=Repositories&ref=advsearch&l=&l=) (which I have not tried yet), but in general most of them will not work given the above limitations:

- https://github.com/simulatedsimian/tracetcp
- https://github.com/trimstray/htrace.sh
- https://github.com/Manisso/Crips
- https://github.com/simulatedsimian/tracetcp

---

Oh, also, I have Google Chrome installed and I can add these extensions:

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ipvfoo/ecanpcehffngcegjmadlcijfolapggal
- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ip-address/ghlojgpiinfelppegaabbiphgomaidml

---

Note: I need to test/verify stuff inside inside my own local network. An online tool or service that runs in the context of a remote server (like for example [this Google Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/network-and-internet-tool/ekpdpmpcgcmpaeokmclflfpadaklgpji?hl=en)) will not do it.

I also cannot use Raw Socket because "only members of the Administrators group can create sockets of type SOCK_RAW on Windows 2000 and later."

Follow up question: https://superuser.com/q/1383578/453021

Comment: I assume you've tried all of the options you found? Why didn't they work?

Comment: Tracert is built in to Windows 7. It does not need to be installed. Neither does it require administrative rights. You might also try pathping, which is also built in to Windows 7.

Comment: @joeqwerty - I think that the admin might have deliberately removed or disabled Tracert.

Comment: @Tim - I have not yet tried the git repos, I just looked at the requirements and most of them will not work given the limitations. Do you see anything that will work?

Comment: Java usually doesn't require installation, sometimes you just double click the .jar file that it comes with. Try it out, what do you have to lose.

Comment: I think I found an answer: https://superuser.com/questions/915657/how-to-simulate-traceroute-using-ping

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think "tracert" on windows require admin permissions. Alternately there's [Open Visual Trace](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openvisualtrace/) written in Java which might do the job.

Comment: Does this utility require Raw Socket or anything else that requires admin privileges?

Comment: You don't know what your limitations are. The only way to know if it'll work is to try it.